# NumPy: Jacobian of matrix with respect to self and 2d extension of diagonal matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

[Jacobian of matrix with respect to itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vb1gd.png)

I am implementing an in-house automatic differentiation module using only native functions of NumPy, and for any kind of matrix operations, constructing a 4D array from a 2D array like the one in the picture seems to show up in different places.

My current approach is quite simple: if I'm given a k-by-d matrix called `a`, I am doing something like

```
r = np.zeros([*a.shape, *a.shape])
for i, j in np.ndindex(a.shape):
    r[i, j, i, j] = a[i,j]
```

However, I realize that this is a generalization of `diag()` where I'm inputting a 2D array to construct a 4D array. Is there any native method in NumPy that supports this? I'm mainly afraid that the for-loop I have will eventually be a bottleneck.

Thanks for your replies in advance!

Comment: shouldn't all elements be either 0 or 1?  Why are `a[i, j]` used?

Comment: Ah, yes, the picture refers specifically to the self-Jacobian situation, but I wanted to know the general case where I want to get a 4D array from the 2D array (as it shows up often in Jacobians).

Comment: is the answer I gave fitting the bill, or are there differences with what you need?

Comment: yes, it's exactly what I was looking for. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all elements are either 0 or 1 (as I believe your picture shows), then:

```py
r = np.identity(np.multiply.reduce(a.shape)).reshape(a.shape + a.shape)
```

If instead you want a fast equivalent of the loop you have written, then use `np.einsum()` to return a writeable view of the generalized diagonal of `r` and assign your array to it:

```py
r = np.zeros(a.shape + a.shape)
np.einsum('ijij->ij', r)[:] = a
```

**Examples**

```py
a = np.arange(6).reshape((2,3))
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])

# Jacobian d/da of a
>>> np.identity(np.multiply.reduce(a.shape)).reshape(a.shape + a.shape)
array([[[[1., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0., 1.],
         [0., 0., 0.]]],


       [[[0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 1., 0.]],

        [[0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 1.]]]])

# set a as the generalized diagonal of a n,m,n,m matrix
r = np.zeros(a.shape + a.shape)
np.einsum('ijij->ij', r)[:] = a
>>> r
array([[[[0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0., 2.],
         [0., 0., 0.]]],


       [[[0., 0., 0.],
         [3., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 4., 0.]],

        [[0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 5.]]]])
```